# How long does quantum Zeno effect last?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurements, time-evolution

Everywhere I read about the quantum Zeno effect, the phrase used is: <"immediately" after the measurement, the system remains in the observed state>. What does "immediately" mean ? 1 nanosecond ? 1 second ? 1 year ? Why is this phrased even used instead of stating exactly the amount of time that the system remains in that state ?

Comment: It depends on the system, there is no universal answer. See also the so-called Zeno-time. Have you considered the most common basic examples? Say, a spin-1/2 particle in a magnetic field?